# get_the_term_list - Return links to edit.php instead of link to taxonomy archive template

Tags: taxonomy, archive-template, terms

I would like to use `get_the_term_list` or another function if it exists to return links to the posts of the appropriate term (which has been clicked) on edit.php instead of returning links to posts of the clicked term on the taxonomy archive page. Can this be achieved?